# Google Sheets Multiple IF statements

Tags: google-sheets

```
A1 = 2

B1 = 5
```

I would like to say:

```
If "A1<B1" and "checkbox C1 is ticked" do "this sum" on a Google Spreadsheet.
```

Everything I have tried so far is returning "N/A". Seems stupidly simple but I can't get to grips with spreadsheets. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
=IF(AND(A1<=B1,C1=TRUE),D1+E1)
```

For anyone else looking for help.